# How to deserialize with JSON.Net where the same type is given different names

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm having to process 3rd party json data. I'm trying to use JSON.Net, but I'm struggling a little as, in the data, the same type is given a different name every time. See example below.

```
{
   "success":"1",
   "return":{
      "Mike":{
         "name":"Mike",
         "age":"21",
         "hobbies":[
            {
               "name":"sailing"
            },
            {
               "name":"volleyball"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here you can see that - in this made up example to illustrate the situation - basically a person object is returned, but it is called "Mike" not person. The next might be called "Sheryl", etc.
I would like to just deserialise the whole thing in one go using:
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

However I'm not sure how to build x as it can vary.

I've looked at JsonConverter, but I can't see how that would help in this situation.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Consider: `[JsonProperty("return")] Dictionary<string, PersonInfo> Result { get; set; }` (the Keys in the dictionary will represent the "Mike" or "Sheryl"). However, I suspect that the server is just returning less-than-ideal information, it should likely be a List (the name is already present in the information), not a Dictionary :|

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @user2864740. I'll look into that too. I've gone with L.B's answer for the minute as it works great. Thanks once again though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Dictionary<string,Person>` for property `Return`

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObject>(json);
```

---

```
public class Hobby
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public List<Hobby> Hobbies { get; set; }
}


public class YourObject
{
    public string Success { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,Person>  Return { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Just that simple. Let me quickly try it out. Thanks for the quick response by the way - that's excellent.

Comment: Oh my god! That totally works. Why have I been beating myself up for the last several days over this. Thank you so much.